# Connect-AzureRMAccount : The term 'Connect-AzureRMAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

I am stuck in a problem in Azure PowerShell. I am not able to connect to AzureRM account. It's showing this error:

> Connect-AzureRMAccount : The term 'Connect-AzureRMAccount' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureRMAccount
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-AzureRMAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I'm doing this in Mac OS . Firstly I've installed the PowerShell using: brew cask install PowerShell.
Then I've done the following:

1. Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser.
2. Install-Module Azure.
3. Install-Module AzureRM.
4. Import-Module AzureRM.
5. Connect-AzureRMAccount (It's Showing me the above Error).

I am expecting step 5 to give me the sign in pop up. Please Help

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago, I fixed it by installing the NuGet package before installing the AzureRM PS module, but it was a Windows 10 device, so can't confirm it would work on Mac.

Comment: What's the output of `get-command *azurerm*` you can follow this to install PowerShell on mac, http://www.thatlazyadmin.com/2169-2/

Comment: I have already tried the solution by the lazy admin .Not helpful!  and get-command *azurerm* is giving 1978 outputs of commands

Comment: What does the NUGet Package does?

Answer (score 10):

The AzureRM module isn't available on macOS.  You will need the Az module.  It has tons of parity and an option for enabling compatible aliases (`Enable-AzureRmAlias`):
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/

Keep in mind that this module is the future, in general (Windows, macOS, and Linux... as well in Azure Cloud Shell).

The following cmdlets are useful:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber
Import-Module Az
Connect-AzAccount
```

Comment: How can i Install the Az module? And then i need to login to azureRM account. Is it possible?

Comment: @AmitJoshi `Install-Module Az` - Do note however: You should not install Az side-by-side with AzureRM. Remove all AzureRM modules before installing Az.

Comment: At this point it is worthwhile to also read the documentation about the new Az module and migration to it below before doing it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-2.0.0